# Computer is slow at boot, mouse blinking. Partially solved after disable mouspad

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, performance, mouse

I have a Packard Bell laptop that last month has a mystery problem.
After user login I have that symptoms:

- Mouse blinking randomly
- Computer is extremelly slow
- All apps are loading extremely slow (even the network icon!)

So, I decided to format it and install again the windows 7.
After format, without any programms, or settings, the symptoms are the same.

I decided to format and install windows 10. I am not lucky guy, so the problem didn't solved.

I noticed that If I "disable" the mousepad (FN+F6) the computer works smoothly without any problem!

**BUT:** It doesn't matters if the mousepad is enabled or diabled, just I have to change the status (from disabled to enabled and opposite). That's the only way to have a working computer as temporary solution.

I have also remove the cable from touchpad (I though that had the problem) but the problem exists.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Today I learned that Packard Bell still exists and sells notebook computers.  That's what I learned today.    How old is this one, though?

Comment: @Cdove I think it's about 6 years old

Comment: This sounds like your motherboard is about to depart the mortal coil....

Comment: Have you updated the BIOS? How about proper drivers for the devices, specifically the mouse/touchpad?

Comment: If disconnecting the pad didn't help, I'd say device drivers aren't so much the problem.  I'd try a BIOS update, but back up any data first, as if your mobo IS going out, that will possibly aggravate the situation.

Comment: I have updated the BIOS from v1.03 to v1.30 with no luck. but I realised that the problem solved just pressing the **Fn key**, without disabling the mousepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Several steps, and with help of guys here, we find a solution.

I observed that pressing the **FN+F6** keys (disabling the mouse), helps the computer speed, and the mouse doesn't flickering.
After detach the mouse from motherboard the problem doesn't solved, so there is no problem with mouse

If I presses the FN+F6 keys (without the mouse), the problem (temporary) solved.

So the problem solved with the combination of keys... or no?

I observed that just pressing the fn key, the computer works!

So, I detached the keyboard, and... I have a fully working computer!!!

Now, I am waiting new keyboard, to check finally it the problem was faulty, or there is a problem with motherboard!

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall system for 2 times, it is not a system issue, but device issue.

I suggest to disable your mousepad(touchpad) in BIOS, then reboot computer again.

If computer runs smoothly, issue is on touchpad, you need to contact manufacturer for hardware maintenance.

Comment: I have updated the BIOS from v1.03 to v1.30 with no luck. but I realised that the problem solved just pressing the **Fn key**, without disabling the mousepad (Also, at bios I have not any option to disable mousepad)

Answer (score 0):

You are a genius for figuring out the <kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> fix. In my case, which is probably the same, <kbd>FN</kbd> in combination with any of the F# keys stopped the problem but only temporarily. Since my laptop keyboard is already broken and I use a USB, I was able to tape down the <kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> key (no funcationality on <kbd>F7</kbd> so it doesn't interfere with operation) so it is continually being pressed.

Surprisingly, this worked like a charm and overnight the problem has not returned. Tape them down!